# Automatic cache-busting for static builds that works well with npm run?

Tags: node.js, caching, pug, browser-cache

I use `npm` as my build tool, by populating the [`scripts` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) with various commands for the tasks I need. I’m satisfied with the setup, except for one small detail: when building for production, I’d like for references to CSS files in `<link>` tags and references to JS files in `<script>` tags to be updated for cache busting (i.e. to be modified by appending `?random_string` to the file names, or similar).

I’m using [`jade`](http://jade-lang.com/), in case there’s a way to do it that way that I missed.

I don’t mind if the solution busts every file, even if they weren’t changed since the last build. What I care is that it does not require me to add complex code to the website itself (like a function with this as its sole purpose); it should preferably be an external command.

So far, I haven’t been able to find an acceptable solution. I’m almost about to resort to a regex, but would really rather have a more robust solution.

Comment: Can you add `src="…?#{Date.now()}"` at the end of every URL in your Jade files?

Comment: Yes I can. That is great, thank you. It’s a perfectly acceptable addition, since it’s contained within the tag. Could you please add it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jade allows executing any piece of Javascript code you can append a datestring at the end of your URL as a query string which is the standard way of invalidating cached scripts:

```
script(src="/app.js?#{Date.now()}")
```

Comment: in pug (jade 2.0+) string interpolation on attributes has been removed. one option is to use ES6 string templates with backticks.

Comment: why even cache then?